# Windows 7 Не гладкое передвижение окна

Tags: windows

Я недавно перешел из Windows 10 к 7 . В винде 10 окна передвигались гладко при перетаскивании. 
Но когда перешел к 7 . и установил вс дрова . погуглил . параметры быстродействия изменил. по любому перерисовка не гладкая и сильно бесит. оставляет за собой отрисовки и стирается не гладко. 
Что делать ? не говорите снова в 10 переходить.

Comment: не согласен, что нужна правка. уверен, данных достаточно и проблема в видеокарте.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в драйвере видеоадаптера.
Скачай последнюю версию драйвера для своей видеокарты и установи.
Что бы узнать модель видеокарты загугли по марке ноутбука, либо, если это не ноутбук, установи программу everest и выясни модель видеокарты.

Comment: Исправил . нужно было просто оценить видео карту

Comment: что значит оценить?